# confirmationDialog re-appears for one second before closing

Tags: ios, swiftui

I use a confirmationDialog on a view I present within a sheet. When I press the cancel button, it closes first, then re-appears for about a second and then closes as expected finally.

When I replace this very confirmationDialog with an Alert (by just exchanging the keywords) everything works as expected.

```
        @State private var item: ItemDTO?
        @State private var showDeletionConfirmation = false

        ...

        ItemListView(
            items: viewModel.items,
            editAction: { editItem in
                item = editItem
            }
        )
        .sheet(item: $item) { editItem in
            ItemView(
                item: editItem,
                deleteAction: { showDeletionConfirmation = true }
            )
            .confirmationDialog(
                "Sure?",
                isPresented: $showDeletionConfirmation,
                actions: {
                    Button("Yes", role: .destructive) {
                        print("Deleting...")
                        item = nil
                    }
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                        showDeletionConfirmation = false
                    }
                },
                message: {
                    Text("Do you want to continue?")
                }
            )
```

Comment: It should work, but seems like it is a bug of SwiftUI, report it to Apple so they can fix it.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the bug with the code above?

Comment: yeah, I reproduced it, but it seemed like a bug when pushing the confirmation dialog. I didn’t debugged deeply, but I’ll try to debug and check when the bool state changes to show two times the dialog.